Analysis of a sequence based on ratios of floors of consecutive powers of a real value
I am currently interested in the following sequence:

Fix a number $x$, and define a sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty = \lfloor x^n \rfloor$ and $(b_n)_{n=0}^\infty = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

With a little Mathematica code
f[x_] = Table[Floor[x^(n + 1)] / Floor[x^(n)], {n, 1, 20}]

I found out some rather interesting observations:
1. How much $x$ appears on the sequence seems to depend on the denominator $n$ and how large the numerator $m$ is, for rational $x = \frac{m}{n}$
I tried for various smaller, rational numbers. It seems that half-integers and fifth-integers ($\frac{a}{5}$ for integer $a$) with smaller integer parts have a larger "frequency" in $b_n$ compared to ones with higher integer parts and having a "farther" distance in their fractional parts. Here are some examples:
f[1.5]
{2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/5, 11/7, 17/11, 25/17, 38/25, 3/2, 86/57, 3/2, \
194/129, 3/2, 437/291, 656/437, 985/656, 1477/985, 2216/1477, \
3325/2216, 4987/3325}

f[4.1]
{4, 17/4, 141/34, 193/47, 2375/579, 41/10, 79849/19475, 327381/79849, \
46285/11289, 1100658/268453, 2256349/550329, 9251031/2256349, 41/10, \
1555098314/379292271, 6375903091/1555098314, 26141202675/6375903091, \
107178930967/26141202675, 439433616966/107178930967, \
900838914782/219716808483, 7386879101213/1801677829564}

Notice how 3/2 seems to appear more in the first list compared to 41/10 in the second. Also I noted that in the case $x$ does appear, its appearance tends to be more towards the beginning of the sequence.
2. The semi-periodic patterns for square root of integers.
Consider f[Sqrt[2]]:
{2, 1, 2, 5/4, 8/5, 11/8, 16/11, 11/8, 16/11, 45/32, 64/45, 45/32, \
64/45, 181/128, 256/181, 181/128, 256/181, 181/128, 256/181, 181/128}

Notice the semi-periodic pattern that eventually changes into another number. However, when we add more terms, the periodicity breaks temporaily, and then seems to return.
f[x_] = Table[Floor[x^(n + 1)]/Floor[x^(n)], {n, 1, 50}]
f[Sqrt[2]]
{2, 1, 2, 5/4, 8/5, 11/8, 16/11, 11/8, 16/11, 45/32, 64/45, 45/32, \
64/45, 181/128, 256/181, 181/128, 256/181, 181/128, 256/181, 181/128, \
256/181, 181/128, 256/181, 181/128, 256/181, 11585/8192, 16384/11585, \
11585/8192, 16384/11585, 11585/8192, 16384/11585, 92681/65536, \
131072/92681, 185363/131072, 262144/185363, 370727/262144, \
524288/370727, 741455/524288, 1048576/741455, 741455/524288, \
1048576/741455, 741455/524288, 1048576/741455, 5931641/4194304, \
8388608/5931641, 11863283/8388608, 16777216/11863283, \
11863283/8388608, 16777216/11863283, 11863283/8388608}

This "pattern" doesn't seem to appear in any other number. Some nearby values also express a periodic pattern in the beginning, but breaks lose, i.e f[7/5]:
{1, 2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/5, 10/7, 7/5, 10/7, 7/5, 10/7, 7/5, ...

(I left the dots as this is when the pattern breaks)
3. Convergence to $x$ for the table.
Define a third sequence $(c_n)_{n=0}^\infty = |b_n - x|$
After another few random tries, it seems that the sequence satisfy $$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} c_n = 0$$, with some entries that are actually very close (show as 0. in Mathematica).
This is just my observation, and sorry for the bad wording as I am quite interested. Does anyone know of a paper or book talking about this subject, as I can't find it anywhere? Thanks!

Related is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153721/floors-of-powers-of-reals-how-much-do-the-first-few-determine-the-next

Note that the limit of $b_n$ is always $x$ because $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x^n+1}<b_n<\frac{x^{n+1}+1}{x^n-1}$ for all $n$ and use the squeeze theorem.

You should assume $|x|>1$, otherwise $b_n$ is not defined as soon as $n\geq 1$. Point 3 is easy to prove assuming $|x|\geq 1$. Here is another proof in addition to @DarkMalthorp 's. If $|x|=1$ you can compute $b_n = x$, so the convergence is immediate. If $|x|>1$ then as $n\to\infty$ we have $a_n/x^n \to 1$ and $a_{n+1}/x^{n+1}\to 1$, thus $b_n \to x$.

thanks @DarkMalthorp and Thomas Lehericy! The other problems are still left to be desired...

Yes! The questions about pseudo-periodicity are super interesting!

In the first question (with fraction $\frac{s}{t}$) you're looking for integers $k$ that satisfy $$\frac{\lfloor\left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^{k+1}\rfloor}{\lfloor\left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^{k}\rfloor} = \frac{s}{t}.$$
Rewriting gives that this happens if and only if $s\mid\lfloor\left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^{k+1}\rfloor$. Heuristically, this is satisfied around $1/s$ times. As large integer parts correspond to large numerators, this will make such an appearance occur less.

For the second question, we find that the $k$-th term (for even $k$) will equal the $k+2$-th term, ..., the $k+2n$-th term and not the $k+2n+2$-th term with $n=\lfloor-\log_2({2^{k/2}\sqrt{2}})\rfloor$, where ${\dots}$ denotes the fractional part of the number.

@jorisperrenet can you provide more explaination and detail to your answer? Thanks in advance!
